# Put into variable each data in SQL command

Tags: php, regex

Any suggestion on how can I put these data into variables.

```
> INSERT INTO process (process, temp) VALUES ('PST_BUMP', '1'), ('IMPORT', '5'), ('IM', '5'), ('PORT', '9')
```

I tried this:

```
<?php
    $statement = "INSERT INTO process (process, temp) VALUES ('PST_BUMP', '1'), ('IMPORT', '5'), ('IM', '5'), ('PORT', '9') ";
    echo $statement . "<br><br>";

    echo $count = substr_count($statement, "), (") . "<br>";

    $remove = str_replace("INSERT INTO process (process, temp) VALUES ", "", $statement);
    echo $remove . "<br><br>";

    $str = (explode("), (",$remove));

    $string= "";

    for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++){
       echo $str[$i] . "<br>"; 
    }

    ?>
```

the result is this:

```
`INSERT INTO process (process, temp) VALUES ('PST_BUMP', '1'), ('IMPORT', '5'), ('IM', '5'), ('PORT', '9') 

3
('PST_BUMP', '1'), ('IMPORT', '5'), ('IM', '5'), ('PORT', '9') 

('PST_BUMP', '1'
'IMPORT', '5'
'IM', '5'
'PORT', '9') `
```

My goal is this:

$proc1 = "PST_BUMP";
$proc2 = "IMPORT";
..so on..

$temp1 = "2";
$temp2 = "3";
.. so on ..

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use variables in "**Insert**" query instead of exact values.

For using variables in insert query, you can write query as:

```
$statement="INSERT INTO process (process, temp) VALUES ('".$proc1."', '".$temp1."'), ('".$proc2."', '".$temp2."'), ('".$proc3"', '".$temp3."')";
```